# Stuck trying to make a simple adder and subtractor

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple web program that just adds and subtracts inputted numbers for a bit of practice, but i'm stuck with not being able to get javascript to store the input value into their designated variables, which are val1 and val2.

Here is the html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Adder and Subtractor</h1>
  <span id="results">0</span><br>
    <input type="number" id="val1"><br>
    <input type="number" id="val2"><br>
  <button class="btn minus">-</button>
  <button class="btn plus">+</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

and the js

```
let count = 0;

let showResult = document.querySelector('#results');

let val1 = document.getElementById('val1').value;
let val2 = document.getElementById('val2').value;

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btn.forEach(function (btns) {
  btns.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    if (styles.contains('minus')){
        count = val1 - val2;
        } else {
          count = val1 + val2;
        }
    showResult.textContent = count;
  })
})
```

Comment: When is your JS executed? On button click you would have to get the values from the input fields again. Otherwise you will always use the old values which were set when the page first loaded.

Comment: Notice you are storing the current value of the elemnt when you do the getElementById,
After the value changes it wouldnt affect your val1 val2,
Im guessing this is why you get the unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You have to get the latest value of each input after the button click. So you should get value in the click listener itself.

```
 btns.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
        let val1 = +document.getElementById( 'val1' ).value;
        let val2 = +document.getElementById( 'val2' ).value;
        ...
    } )
```

**2)** You should convert it to type `Number` before any arithmetic operation. You can also `parseInt`. Below are both types, where you can convert it to `Number` type

```
    let val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById( 'val1' ).value);
    let val2 = +document.getElementById( 'val2' ).value;
```

```js
let count = 0;

let showResult = document.querySelector('#results');


const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btn.forEach(function(btns) {
  btns.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let val1 = +document.getElementById('val1').value; // change
    let val2 = +document.getElementById('val2').value; // change
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    if (styles.contains('minus')) {
      count = val1 - val2;
    } else {
      count = val1 + val2;
    }
    showResult.textContent = count;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Adder and Subtractor</h1>
  <span id="results">0</span><br>
  <input type="number" id="val1"><br>
  <input type="number" id="val2"><br>
  <button class="btn minus">-</button>
  <button class="btn plus">+</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. This did the trick, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the issue with your code?**

You defined `val1` and `val2` at the initial part of code which will keep the initial value of the input. Even if you update the input field value, the values kept in `val1` and `val2` will not be updated.

**Solution**

Either move the entire `val1` and `val2` declaration inside the click listner function OR make the `val1` and `val2` as the selectors for the two input fields and access its values inside the click listner. I went for the second approach here.

**Also** keep in mind that even if you make your input field as `type="number"`, the value for those input fields will be rendered as string. So normal mathematical operations like addition will perform string operations such as concatenation. To avoid that use some numeric conversion ligic such as `parseInt` or `Number` functions, or simply add a `+` before your value to convert the string value into number.

```js
let count = 0;

let showResult = document.querySelector('#results');

let val1 = document.getElementById('val1');
let val2 = document.getElementById('val2');

const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

btn.forEach(function (btns) {
  btns.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const styles = e.currentTarget.classList;
    if (styles.contains('minus')) {
      count = +val1.value - +val2.value;
    } else {
      count = +val1.value + +val2.value;
    }
    showResult.textContent = count;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Adder and Subtractor</h1>
  <span id="results">0</span><br>
  <input type="number" id="val1"><br>
  <input type="number" id="val2"><br>
  <button class="btn minus">-</button>
  <button class="btn plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why this answer was not approved even if this was posted first with all the detals?